# Delete folder in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online

Can anyone tell me how to recover a map accidentally deleted in arcgis online  from the Delete folder?  The delete folder says theres currently 14 items in there .

Comment: While I agree with @Russ below, I am intrigued by this "Delete folder" you mention.  Where/what is that?

Comment: There's a delete folder under the Contents tab in your ArcGIS Online account. You also have the option of creating new folders by clicking 'New Folder' under the Contents tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover a map/item that has been deleted. To prevent this it is best to enable delete protection on the item.

Comment: Thank you very much for verification.  I discovered the same thing in further research.